Where can I find the classification/name for this abstract polyhedra?
Edit: It seems this shape is a "stacked abstract non-convex polytope." This should have a name or Schafli symbol given that it's basically $4$, $\lbrace2,\infty \rbrace$-gons that mutually intersect, and get glued therein.
Relevant links: apeirogonal hosohedron,Schläfli symbol.

While perusing literature on discrete geometry and polyhedra I wondered:

Is there any name or classification for a stellated octahedron but with the base triangles sitting on spheres?

Say the spherical triangles are equilateral with angles $72^°$. Another way to think of this shape is as $9$ three-cells glued together, where the 8 3-cells corresponding to the abstract triangular prisms get glued together in such a way that they enclose the final "interior" three-cell.
I think this implies existence of quartic cycles as well. Certainly this must be a curved/abstract polyhedron? Schafli symbol?
The curvature on this shape is baffling but we must have Euler char. $\chi(S)=0$ where $S$ is the shape I'm considering and we know that the stellated octahedron has zero Euler char. The geometry seems very hyperbolic, but also very spherical from different vantage points.
Anyhow, is this shape $S$ classified somewhere as a curved/abstract polyhedra? I feel like it should have Schafli symbol $\lbrace14, \cdot \rbrace$ because of the $14$ vertices.
Here's what it might look like:

Could it be related to $4$ digons? I know the Schaffli symbols for those already.

polyhedra is plural; polyhedron is singular

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacked_polytope this seems on the right path. Perhaps it can be called a "stacked abstract polytope."
